# Package "acro": Displaying umlaut in PDF bookmark for acronyms list

Tags: xetex, hyperref, acro

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass[ngerman,]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    \printacronyms

\end{document}
```

The PDF bookmark for the list of acronyms reads "Abkurzungen" instead of "Abkürzungen". **Is there any way to change this?** Umlaute in other sections are displayed correctly.

Comment: I opened an issue at acro https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/issues/211.

Comment: Thanks for opening the issue. I can't really get behind the how's and why's of this bug but it seems the developer has acknowledged the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pdflatex it is not really possible. acro must be changed here. With xelatex/lualatex you can reset the name:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\blub{Abkürzung}

\DeclareAcroTranslation {list-name}
  {
    German     = Abkürzung
  }  

\begin{document}

 \printacronyms

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly!